# npm prompt user for password behind corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

When using npm behind corporate proxy we have need to have following configurations in `.npmrc` file in user home directory.

```
proxy = http://<username>:<pass>@<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>/
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
https-proxy = http://<username>:<pass>@<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>/
```

While this works fine, there is a need to hardcode password in the `.npmrc` file. Also corporate password change policy mandates to change password after a certain period of time.

Is there a way/configuration to prompt user for password instead of having it in `.npmrc` file. May be like the way it works for `git clone` where it asks for password while cloning if repository is password protected.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the `sync-prompt` module:

```
npm install sync-prompt
```

and modify the `npm-registry-client/index.js` slightly.

See this article for details and code that you need to add:

- https://mikesharp.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/getting-npm-to-prompt-for-username-and-password-pochack/